# Xcode 4.3.1 syntax errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, syntax

I'm pretty new to coding on Xcode (or objective-c in general) and I can't seem to get rid of these errors:

```
  //
    //  HelloWorldLayer.m
    //  FirstGame
    //
    //  Created by Kostas on 1/14/12.
    //  Copyright __MyCompanyName__ 2012. All rights reserved.
    //


    // Import the interfaces
    #import "HelloWorldLayer.h"
    #import "GamePlay.h"

    // HelloWorldLayer implementation
    @implementation HelloWorldLayer
    +(id) scene {

        CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

        HelloWorldLayer *layer = [HelloWorldLayer node];
        // add layer as a child to scene
        [scene addChild: layer];
        // return the scene
        return scene;
    }

    // on "init" you need to initialize your instance

    -(id) init {

        if( (self=[super init] )) {

            [CCMenuItemFont setFontName:@"Marker Felt"];
            [CCMenuItemFont setFontSize:35];
            CCMenuItem *Play = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"PLAY"
                                target:self
                                selector:@selector(gotoGameplay:)];

            CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems: Play, nil];
            menu.position = ccp(240, 160);
            [menu alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding:10];
            [self addChild:menu];
        }

        return self;
    }

    -(void) goToGameplay: (id) sender {

        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] 
               replaceScene:[[CCTransitionFade 
                    transitionWithDuration:1 
                    scene:[GamePlay node]
                              ]];   **<-----Here is my error it says "Expected identifier"**
    }


    - (void) dealloc {


        [super dealloc];
    }
    @end
```

The expected identifier is just what X-Code came up with.

Answer (score 1):

If you count your brackets, you'll see that you have two more opening brackets than closing brackets. I've indented them here so you can see the problem clearly.

```
-(void) goToGameplay: (id) sender {
    [
      [CCDirector sharedDirector] 
      replaceScene:
      [ // <-- either this is extra
        [CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1
                                           scene:[GamePlay node]
        ]
      ];
  //];   <-- or this is missing
}
```

The compiler is trying to tell you that it wasn't expecting to find a semicolon in the middle of a message send expression. I'm not familiar enough with the Cocos2D framework to know what exactly you're trying to do, but at least you can see what problem is.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] 
           replaceScene:[[CCTransitionFade 
                transitionWithDuration:1 
                scene:[GamePlay node]
                          ]];
```

has 5 open brackets and only 4 close brackets. There needs to be the same number (and in the right places). Most likely you need to get rid of one of the two open brackets after `replaceScene:`.

BTW - why are you using such and old Xcode? You should use the latest - 4.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] 
               replaceScene:[[CCTransitionFade 
                    transitionWithDuration:1 
                    scene:[GamePlay node]
                              ]];
```

to,

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:
        [CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1
                                           scene:[GamePlay node]]];
```

That should fix the issue. You had an extra `[` before `[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1 scene:[GamePlay node]]`